# Safe, easily detectable gas or aerosol for testing fume hoods

Tags: safety, home-experiment

I've recently started undertaking a project to construct a small fume hood. So far I'm considering its use for soldering, 3d printing with ABS and polystyrene, and PCB etching using a muriatic acid/hydrogen peroxide solution, however I'd also like to leave my options open. I want to test the fume hood once completed - I've seen some videos that use dry ice for this purpose, and I figure I might also be able to test the hood by smell using bathroom deodorant, but I'm wondering what sort of concentration these would have to reach in order for me to detect them, and whether there are any other tests I might consider.

Comment: Smoke generation is preferred over smell, as the visual test is a bit more objective.  See [this reference](http://www.wcsu.edu/efs/hs_pdffiles/s113_lfhpt.pdf) for more info, although $\ce{TiCl4}$ is not available for home use.  An anemometer might be of help as well.

Comment: @bobthechemist That's darn close to being a full answer, so feel free to add it if you'd like.

Comment: @16 If you have any doubt as to whether this is a safe setup, please consult a professional or at minimum someone with experience in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smoke generation is preferred over smell, as the visual test is a bit more objective. See [this reference](http://www.wcsu.edu/efs/hs_pdffiles/s113_lfhpt.pdf) for more info, although $\ce{TiCl4}$is not available for home use. There are hobbyist alternatives such as [smoke matches](http://www.amazon.com/Copperfield-41509-Smoke-Test-Matches/) which will help you test the fume hood performance. (The above link is just an example, I did see better prices at less-known websites.)  An anemometer might be of help as well.

Comment: Why not use dry ice in water, as a cheap alternative to a fog machine?  Or rent a fog machine from the local party supply store?

Comment: @AbelFriedman certainly possible, depending on what one has available in the lab.